# Getting current vertex position of vertex on rotation

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, transformation, vertex

I have a very simple program with my introductor OpenGL stuff. I have 3d vertex on the screen and the whole system is being rotated along y axis.

```
float rotation =0;
//update function
rotation = rotation +1;
```

The draw function looks something like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(500,390,0);
        glRotatef(rotation,0.0,1.0,0.0);
        glVertex3d(365,50,0);
glPopMatrix();
```

When the glVertex is being rotated, its position *on the screen* is changing obviously. But the coordinates of the point itself are not. How do I get the `current` coordinates of the point on the screen which has been rotated by `glRotatef`, when their 'actual' coordinates are stationary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I get the current coordinates of the point on the screen which has been rotated by glRotatef, when their 'actual' coordinates are stationary?

You have to mimick the OpenGL transformation pipeline. Since you're using old-and-dusted fixed function OpenGL, I'm going to show you how to do this with old-and-dusted *GLU*:

First we need the current viewport and projection matrix

```
GLint viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

GLdouble projection[16];
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(500,390,0);
    glRotatef(rotation,0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

at this point the modelview matrix holds the modelview transform applied so get this one, too.

```
GLdouble modelview[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
```

Now we have everything to project it.

```
GLdouble obj_x, obj_y, obj_z; // point coordinates
GLdouble win_x, win_y, win_z; // receives window coordinates
gluProject( obj_x, obj_y, obj_z,
            modelview, projection, viewport,
            &win_x, &win_y, &win_z );
```

There you go. I recommend looking at the sourcecode of gluProject as provided by MesaGL. But basically it's these steps:

```
clip = Projection · Modelview · obj{x,y,z,w}
clip = clip / clip.w;
win{x,y} = viewport{x,y} + viewport{width,height} * (clip{x,y} + 1)/2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I saw some of your answers on CG and 3D topics and wanted to ask for your help around here with a similar question but a little extended when I tried to use the above answer. The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424768/hit-testing-between-four-rotating-vertices I have been kind of stuck on this for quite some time and it would be greta if you could help with the solution there. Thanks for writing the answer here once again!

Answer (score 0):

get the ModelView Matrix just before calling `glVertex3d(365,50,0);`

```
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ptr)
```

where ptr is a pointer to an float array. So after you get that matrix multiply it with vertex position and you will get rotated position. Use GLM library for easy matrix operation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first draw your objects with their centroid in the origin `(0, 0, 0)`.

Then, when you call the function:

```
GLfloat matrixMV[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrixMV);
```

the coordinates `(x, y, z)` will be respectively (`matrixMV[12], matrixMV[13], matrixMV[14])`.